# myIntent.getStringExtra returns null?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having a weird problem when I try to send strings with intents when switching activities.

Here is what I do in class 1:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchText.this, Search.class);  
myIntent.putExtra("searchx", spinnerselected);  
myIntent.putExtra("SearchText", input);  
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Class 2:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();   
searchText=myIntent.getStringExtra("SearchText");  
spinnerselectednumber=Integer.parseInt(myIntent.getStringExtra("searchx"));
```

And using the debugger in the second class, its clear that there is a value in 
[searchx](http://i51.tinypic.com/jj1ctx.png).

Though the line `myIntent.getStringExtra("searchx")` returns `null`  .

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Was `spinnerSelected`  a String?

---

[From the Javadoc for Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

> ```
> public String getStringExtra(String name)
> ```
>
> **Since:** API Level 1
>
> **Description:** Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *name* The name of the desired item.
>
> **Returns:** The value of an item that previously added with `putExtra()` or null if no String value was found.

---

There seems to be many ways to retrieve "extras" - whatever the type of `spinnerSelected` was, try to retrieve it using the appropriate method.
Eg if it was an int:

```
public int getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `.ToString()` to `myIntent.putExtra("searchx", spinnerselected);` so that it is `myIntent.putExtra("searchx", spinnerselected.ToString());` This always works for me

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        return extras != null ? extras.getString("searchx")
                : "nothing passed in";
```

Comment: No, his problem is that he's putting the value in incorrectly. Aiden is on the right track.